# How to find a particular code, style: width is added to the body tag?

Tags: css

I am a bit clueless as i can't seem to find where the extra style code is set.

This is the body tag as source code

```
<body class="home page page-id-3505 page-template page-template-template-blog-isotope-php logged-in admin-bar no-customize-support boxed responsive-yes wpb-js-composer js-comp-ver-3.7.4 vc_responsive">
```

but with inspector i see a style being added add the end of the body tag.

```
<body class="home page page-id-3505 page-template page-template-template-blog-isotope-php logged-in admin-bar boxed responsive-yes wpb-js-composer js-comp-ver-3.7.4 vc_responsive customize-support" style="width: 262px;">
```

see the extra `style="width:262px"`.

Things i tried:

1 Now at first i was thinking my Chrome browser was set to mobile or something but that isn't the case i also check with firefox.

2 Using netbeans i did a search for 262px but no result

Any other tips?

regards

Comment: Some javascript modfied your style-attribute. You are using some frameworks, aren't you?

Comment: it is at runtime set by jquery or javascript. can you provide any link

Comment: Its added with JavaScript. You will need to dig into your '.js' files to find where this has been set but it will not be that easy to find unless you know what you are looking for. Also, if you are using the compressed script files (.min.js), you will NEVER find it. If you can post a link to your site, someone will be able to help you identify where its added.

Comment: @tjati, yep they passed a Wordpress theme. going to explore the .js files wf4 any .js to strip the style css from the body tag?

Comment: You can remove the style-tag with `$('body').removeProp('style');`

Comment: Tx tjati, i was trying removeAttr without succes, still need to find where it is set

Answer (score 2):

`style="width:262px"`  is `inline-css` so it wont be present in any of `.css` files....ideally it should be present in your HTML file itself, `inside <body> tag`

If you cant find it in HTML, my best guess is that some `jQuery` or `javascript` is adding this to your code, as it appears, you are using `page-template` meaning some pre-defined template with `JS` may be!!

One solution is to open all `.js` files in your IDE and run a search for the same or `$('body')` in all open documents

Comment: looking in the IDE, what for exactly?? It could be set using `.width()`, `.attr()` and the 262 is most likely a dynamic value so that would not be there either... What I would suggest to search for would be `$('body')`.

Comment: @wf4 : there is `search`  function in all IDE's, which OP could use with class keyword like `$('body')` and not numeric value (*as u thought*)....that sounds pretty *obvious way to search* for me....dont u think?? :)

Comment: I think that searching in the IDE is the correct thing to do @NoobEditor , my point was that you suggested to `search for the same in all open documents`, which would not have helped. I just made a suggestion as to what the OP should be looking for. :-)

Answer (score -1):

This style may be added dynamically depending on the brower width or some other parameter,Element style not added through css file,it ll be added through your js file.

Answer (score -2):

This 'style="width:262px"' is runtime generated by Jquery/Javascript. If you want to reset it you can try the below code..

```
body{width:100% !important;}
```

You can set width which you want instead "100%"

Comment: It works on fixing the outcome after it's already achieved, not the actual initial reason.

Comment: Its not really a good approach to take, there are some times where you can, and should use `!important`, this is not one of them.